# Java. Сборка war gradle

Tags: java, websocket, gradle, сборка, war

Начал изучать систему сборки gradle. Написал приложение с использованием websocket(Sockjs). Запускаю из idea, всё работает. Запускаю tomcat на этой же ide или деплою war-файл в какой-нибудь контейнер сервлетов, и приложение не работает. В консоли веб-страницы:

```
Opening Web Socket...
GET http://localhost:9917/chat-messaging/info?t=1528500208125 404 ()
Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:9917/chat-messaging
```

Дело в конфигурации build.gradle или в моём плохом понимании websocket-а? :)
И при создании jar-файла зависимые пакеты не подтягиваются.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'ru.bakhuss'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

jar {
    baseName = 'StringReverse'
    version = '0.1.0'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ru.bakhuss.stringReverse.Application'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.193'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'webjars-locator', version: '0.32-1'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'sockjs-client', version: '1.1.2'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'stomp-websocket', version: '2.3.3-1'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: А из IDEA вы запускаете как обычное приложение или в Tomcat? web.xml настраивали для spring? Если я правильно понял, вы за основу используете spring?

Comment: Да, как основу использую spring.
Из IDEA если запускать как обычное приложение, то работает, если в Tomcat, то не работает.
А web.xml для spring с аннотациями нужен?

Comment: Посмотрите доки по Spring, скорее всего нужны какие-то настройки для развертывания в Tomcat.